# Override category pages with a URL rewrite

Tags: magento

I cannot figure out how to override what displays on certain category pages with the url rewrite tool.

For example I have a category [here](http://www.site.com/systems). This category also has sub categories, which I want to keep, such as [this one](http://www.site.com/systems/electronics).

I created a new page (www.site.com/newpage/), it's here and working.

I want the content of this new page to display when people go to the 'systems' category URL.

In URL re-write management I create 'custom' and choose

```
ID Path : newpage
Request Path : newpage
Target Path : systems
Redirect : No
```

also tried

```
ID Path : newpage
Request Path : systems
Target Path : newpage
Redirect : No
```

Neither seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [How to use category to show static pages](http://blog.magestore.com/2010/06/15/how-to-use-category-to-show-static-pages/)

Instead of using url rewrite, you could go to `Admin -> Catalog > Manage Categories` then edit your existing category to make it show as a static block, by navigate to "Display settings" tab and select ‘Static block only’ in display mode drop down field.